# WHM / CPANEL / dedicated hosting / see all configured Forwarders

Tags: cpanel, whm, dedicated-server, email-forwarding

I have a dedicated hosting with WHM / CPANEL.

Instead to going to all cpanels, is there a way to view all configured email Forwarders of all my domains ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My web hosting provider told me to check /etc/valiases/ directory

and its all there ;)